# Android: Why does EditText make scrolling slow?

Tags: android

I created a scrollable custom ViewGroup which has several >200 EditTexts in it (not all of them are shown at the same time - I am using a recycler). The problem I am having is that the scrolling is very slow.

Interestingly, I don't have the problem if I do one of the following
1) disable the editText [editText.setEnabled(false)]

or

2) If I change the view from EditText to TextView

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: As a good practice you must not do this.
Like ListView you must keep reference of only those views which are being displayed to the user and recycle which are no more in display area of the screen.

Comment: 200 EditTexts? for what?

Comment: I don't think EditText was designed with this kind of use case in mind...What is your use case?

Comment: Trickster - I wrote a custom recycler and it is working fine when the editTexts are not enable or if I use TextView. That is why I am confused. I guess I should have clarified it (I have edited my question now)

Comment: Ginovva and Glenn - I am trying to create a spreadsheet app, where each cell is a EditText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EditText is [huge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). Take a look especially at all those methods it inherits.

Why don't you try using just one EditText with 199 custom TextViews or a large grid of rectangles drawn within a Canvas? You could always customize your TextViews (or your drawn grid of rectangles) to make them look like edit boxes, but only use one EditText for the cell that has the focus itself.

That's even how Excel works for *some* of the functionality it has. It can edit a cell directly (yes), but it also has a static cell on the upper left of the Excel spreadsheet to show you the content of a formula (that may already be rendered as a view within the focused cell itself). You could do something similar yourself. You could extend an EditText to do all the hard stuff, like auto-complete, etc, but you could just draw the text inside the rectangle that has focus (or insert it inside the particular TextView that has focus).

Take a look at this example: 
https://github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet

He seems to be using mostly TextViews (although TextViews are heavy too, I'm starting to think that the Canvas may be better for something like this, and that everything could be simulated with the drawing method, by everything I mean the blinking cursor, the highlighting of the cell, the character by character typing, etc). With the Canvas at least, you can easily tell it what part needs to be drawn, and what part is off the screen and doesn't need to be drawn, so you're less likely to get into memory problems.

Comment: Stephan. Yes, making and rendering EditText may be one of the reasons (please see my response to user myCode above). Using a single editText sounds interesting. I was not aware that it is possible. Will I have control over each one of the cells (so I can read or write to them)?

Comment: Stephan, your ideas seem to be the path to go. Built-in android UI views are slow.

Answer (score 1):

It can be issue with focusing the EditText during the scroll or you create too much objects and it is slow. Use ListView with EditText. Recycle views using viewHolder pattern. It will be smooth but I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: myCode - thanks for your response. I am recycling the Views. When I set the setEnabled as false the scroll is very smooth (so I think the recycler is working). I suspect a couple of things

Comment: 1) As you mentioned, focusing is messing something up during touch event handling 2) EditTexts are costly to render. I am not sure if I am in the right direction

Comment: How you recycle the views?

Comment: I maintain an array of views. I add a view to that array when it goes out of the scroll region and when I need a new view, I obtain a view from this array and send it to the getView function of the adapter